# Why is my laravel batch failing randomly with ModelNotFoundException?

Tags: laravel, jobs, job-scheduling

I have a batch that is scheduled to run every day at 00:05.
On some days, a job in the batch fails immediately with the ModelNotFoundException.
However, the model that was not found does exist.

[image: Horizon batches]
[image]
[image]
[image]

There were no change to any of the concerned models in the database. (Field, Category, Condition)

There is also no code in the application that allows to delete the category.

Retrying the job manually from the horizon dashboard make the job pass.

The dba said there are no error in the logs and no scheduled maintenance at that time.
What can possibly cause this?

Comment: _we can't see the code_, but in stacktrace there is method `RestoreModel`, so if model has relation with `Category` and restoring **that** model doesn't restore related category or many-to-many relation (which probably also deleted) then referencing category might produce your problem

Comment: That is a good hint, but I don't think this is the the answer in my case. The category table hasn't changed for months, and we never delete records, which is why I wonder why sometimes I get this errors.

Comment: We're experiencing similar issues in a project here at work, but on top of that we're also having inserts not creating rows in MySQL but returning the ids, making Laravel think the creation was successful. Can you confirm you're also using MySQL, and maybe more specific, MySQL 8.x?

Comment: I am using sql server 2019. I have not yet found what is causing this issue.